# mips assembly で文字列中のあるパターンの出現を調べる

Tags: c, assembly, mips

以下は,文字列中のあるパターンの出現を調べるプログラムである.18 行目の End はプログラムの終了を表すものとする.
• 入力は,それぞれ char 型の配列 Pat(ベースアドレス$s0) と,Str(ベースアドレス$s1) に与えられる.両方の文字列の終端には NULL 文字 (\0,ASCII コード 0) が置かれている.
• 文字列 Str にパターン Pat が出現する都度,その先頭の位置を整数配列 AP(ベースアドレス $s2) に記憶し,また,総出現回数をレジスタ$s3 に出力する.例えば,入力が Pat="ABC",Str="ABCAABCBABC"の場合,AP[0]=0,AP[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x2hs.png)=4,AP[2]=8,$s3=3 が出力される.
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Main:
add $s3, $zero, $zero 
add $t4, $zero, $zero

LoopO: add $t0, $s0, $zero 
add $t1,$s1,$t4

LoopI: lb $t2, 0($t0)
beq $t2, $zero, Find 
lb $t3,0($t1)
beq $t3,$zero,Fin
bne $t2,$t3,Next
addi $t0,$t0,1
addi $t1,$t1,1
j LoopI

Find: 
sw $t4,0($s2)
addi $s2,$s2,4
addi $s3,$s3,1

Next : 
addi $t4,$t4,$t1
j Loop0

Fin:End

このようなコードで、うまくいけない、もし配列　str と　配列pat にマッチする文字がない時、next にジャンプしても　$t4　がずっと 同じ値ので、LOOP0にジャンプする時、add $t1,$s1,$t4　の命令によって、配列str の中にずっと同じ文字に指す
どうすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

走査開始(`LoopO`)の時点で、`$t4` に予め値をセットしておけば良いのではないでしょうか(`sub $t4, $t1, $s1`)。

```
Main:
  la  $s0, pat
  la  $s1, str
  la  $s2, index
  add $s3, $zero, $zero
  add $t1, $s1, $zero

LoopO:
  add $t0, $s0, $zero
  sub $t4, $t1, $s1    # Set new starting index

LoopI:
  lb   $t2, 0($t0)
  beq  $t2, $zero, Find
  lb   $t3, 0($t1)
  beq  $t3, $zero, Fin
  addi $t1, $t1, 1
  bne  $t2, $t3, LoopO
  addi $t0, $t0, 1
  j    LoopI

Find:
  sw   $t4, 0($s2)
  addi $s2, $s2, 4
  addi $s3, $s3, 1
  addi $t1, $t1, 1
  j    LoopO

Fin:
  li $v0, 10
  syscall

.data
pat: .asciiz "ABC"
str: .asciiz "ABCAABCBABC"
index: .word 0:10
```

Comment: ありがとうございました！。この問題は、点々の部分のみに追加することが完成できますか（？）何回読んでも、答えがうまく見つかりませんでした